# return dynamic message from class in flutter

Tags: flutter, class

Im trying to build flutter app
that has a feature which is using keypoint of posenet  to detect some poses
I start from this code and modify BndBox class
https://heartbeat.fritz.ai/implementing-real-time-pose-estimation-on-mobile-using-flutter-af281d3740df

```
    if (((kx[3] - kx[5]).abs() <= 0.05) &&
        ((kx[3] - kx[11]).abs() <= 0.1)) {
      widget.setMsg = "this is right";
      print("this is right");
    } else if (((kx[3] - kx[5]) > 0.05 && (kx[3] - kx[5]) < 0.1) &&
        (((kx[3] - kx[11]) > 0.1) && (kx[3] - kx[11]) < 0.2)) {
      setState(() {
        widget.setMsg = "this is right";
      });
      print("this is wrong ");
      setState(() {
        widget.setMsg = "this is wrongg";
      });
      widget.setMsg = "this is wrong";
    } else {
      setState(() {
        widget.setMsg = "undefined";
      });
      widget.setMsg = "undefined";
      print("undetected");
    }
  }
```

return lists;
}

```
return Stack(children: widget.model == posenet ? _renderKeypoints() : null);
```

now  my program return list of widget (the ket point )I also want to return the msg("this is wrong ", "this is right"....
I tried to make the stack return the renderKeypoints() ((list of widget )) and widget text but it doesn't work
tried to make variable "msg="start" in my class and pass it to home class but its just keep "start " and did not change to the messages I assigned it to ...

Comment: I see that you are using `setState` in your Keypoints' widget but how are you notifying the stack of these updates so it rebuilds as well. 
I think the issue is you are rebuilding the keypoints but the stack and parent widgets are not notified of these changes so updates are not visible.

Comment: thank you .how to solve  it?

Comment: i put this in parent class   setMsg(msg) {
    setState(() {
      _msgs = msg;
    });
  }
///////// BndBox(
                  _recognitions == null ? [] : _recognitions,
                  math.max(_imageHeight, _imageWidth),
                  math.min(_imageHeight, _imageWidth),
                  screen.height,
                  screen.width,
                  _model,
                  setMsg,
                ), Text(
                  _msgs == "" ? "nothing" : _msgs,
                )/////////
the text show nothing ,,,,nothing happens